# Modifying binary classification to Multi-Class Classification (Logistic Regression)

Tags: python, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I am using this code that I found here for logistic regression for binary classification with 2 classes.

https://github.com/datafleets/horizontal-federated-learning-blog/blob/master/horizontal-fl.ipynb

The data that I am testing with is calling for multi-class classification (6 classes).

Can I use the same code found above if I have 6 classes? Such that the prediction falls into one of the classes or activities (walking, walkingupstairs, walkingdownstairs, sitting, standing, lying).

https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/human-activity-recognition-with-smartphones

Any advice is highly appreciated.

**update:**
I have tried to change the model in set_weights and train_model from

```
model=linear_model.SGDClassifier()
```

to

```
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr', max_iter=1000, random_state=20)
```

but its not working !!!!!!

```
TypeError: '(array([402, 286, 419, 194, 644, 151, 127, 567, 359,   7, 616, 209, 465,
       546, 144, 182, 582, 528, 263, 192, 185, 690, 241, 211,  36, 296,
       143, 637, 401, 264,  74, 365, 385, 700,  28, 514, 406, 606, 328,
       410, 673, 726, 260, 276, 572, 103, 398, 267, 256, 550, 563, 321,
        46, 203, 463, 195, 702, 405, 343, 392, 476, 670,  60, 427, 474,
       197, 645,  55, 610, 175, 647, 367, 641, 364, 573, 593, 213, 251,
       366, 489, 262, 706, 268, 140, 730, 345, 425, 512, 487, 608,  61,
       319, 115, 284,  99, 409, 456, 464, 310, 727, 313, 447, 125, 400,
       481, 181, 722, 322, 352, 325, 375, 171, 347, 714, 318, 294, 655,
       383, 164, 141,  89, 253, 513, 293, 633, 530, 568, 350, 157, 218,
         5, 468, 155, 547,   1, 496,  76, 624, 395, 643, 397, 139, 266,
       721, 255, 196, 170, 583, 622, 349, 459,  49, 515, 179, 215,  27,
       698, 704, 581,  71, 537, 661, 107, 129, 500, 399,  38, 339, 600,
       564, 679, 326, 615, 231, 305, 176, 617, 225, 467, 353,  35, 723,
        82,  92, 334,  16, 230, 686, 440, 455, 101, 435, 521, 189, 295,
       220, 205, 362, 363, 242, 493, 154, 495, 420, 597, 710, 660,  79,
       344, 628, 707, 720, 450, 333, 243, 239, 236, 559, 689,  50, 120,
       108, 498, 329, 372, 477, 497, 502, 626, 360,  62, 436, 148, 434,
       540, 370, 542, 109, 407,  41, 130, 575, 638, 177, 183,  40, 691,
       439, 158, 671,  53, 556, 548, 279, 228, 506, 156, 659, 636,  95,
       371,  19, 412,  39, 348, 377, 566,  14, 443, 240, 390, 428, 100,
       229, 532, 501, 237, 404, 475, 423, 551, 553, 257,  17, 664, 373,
        66, 729, 601, 159, 499, 314,  86, 433, 522, 524,  96, 351, 238,
       165, 642, 719,  42, 186, 217, 336, 374, 571, 299, 278, 316, 718,
       309, 437,  75, 393, 574, 162, 557, 713, 529,   2,  32, 672, 486,
        29,  10,  84, 270, 453, 442, 562,  26, 356, 288, 461, 509, 711,
       355, 346,  45, 701, 519, 135, 525, 303, 152, 577, 684, 651,  91,
         6, 591, 460, 161, 222, 254, 387, 160, 283, 683, 488, 607, 479,
        78, 538, 394, 199, 269,  31, 457, 630,  68, 535, 623, 658, 180,
       611,   0,  63, 511, 482, 212,  13,   9, 248, 214, 668, 190, 579,
       517, 149, 484, 552, 444, 682, 124, 386, 697, 118, 543, 297, 112,
       424, 308,  21, 138, 411, 648, 639, 470, 210,  56, 280,  18,  33,
       667, 324, 445, 508, 272, 249, 545, 287, 202,  43, 632, 709, 678,
       235, 587, 430, 654, 656, 223, 687, 491,  25, 187,  85, 677, 458,
       408,   3, 134,  30,  23,  15, 614, 657, 292, 131, 233,  12, 724,
       198, 145,  59, 178, 734, 304, 403, 712, 396, 596, 332, 142, 281,
       301, 216, 116, 376, 106,  88, 646, 174, 503, 603,  34, 389, 358,
       110, 341, 167, 416, 302, 146, 681, 485, 317, 570, 361, 438, 219,
       388, 422,  70, 415,  73, 132, 618, 733, 191, 728, 426, 380, 505,
       688, 261, 111, 588, 699,  77, 122, 137, 166, 612, 227,  94, 695,
       592, 717, 330, 716, 446, 311,  93, 494, 173, 452, 674, 282,  24,
       431, 391,  57, 539, 207,  69, 413, 555, 441,  90, 676, 153, 421,
       201,   4, 629, 432, 472, 594, 554, 451, 731, 478, 119, 483, 634,
       289, 666, 273, 703, 640,  22, 578, 705, 580, 265, 449, 369, 354,
       384, 662, 105, 584, 234, 586, 277, 680, 585, 469, 298, 480, 121,
       536, 417, 527,   8, 315, 306, 605, 275,  11, 454, 516, 340,  54,
       549, 693, 113,  58, 589, 184, 665, 320,  47, 102, 448, 337,  52,
       274, 627, 418, 259,  87, 569, 685, 471, 379, 381,  37, 526, 631,
       590, 669, 725, 378, 128, 533,  65,  72, 342, 335, 504, 221,  48,
       675, 252, 307, 692, 245, 708, 188, 200, 561, 150, 715,  83, 599,
       732, 531, 114, 285, 625,  20, 126, 382, 635, 104, 123, 291, 598,
       541, 649,  51, 534, 414, 331, 694, 163, 206, 258, 652, 224, 576,
       204,  80,  64, 518, 133, 602, 650, 492, 558, 250, 290, 312, 327,
       208, 338, 246, 271, 696,  98,  44, 117, 609, 323, 466,  81, 462,
       247, 621, 544, 613, 604, 523, 147, 429, 193, 595, 244, 619, 520,
       300, 565, 653, 172, 473, 226, 168, 620, 368,  67, 169, 490, 510,
       507, 232, 560, 663, 357,  97, 136]),)' is an invalid key
```

Comment: 1. Data science questions are for the data science stack exchange: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kate-melnykova thank you for your valuable reply, I already did since two weeks with no hints or straightforward answer

Comment: Did you try one-vs-rest and one-vs-one?

Comment: kate-melnykova@  I have tried to change the model in set_weights and train_model 
from model=linear_model.SGDClassifier() to model=OneVsRestClassifier(SVC()), but its not working !!!!!!

Comment: That's not how one-vs-rest and one-vs-one works. One-vs-one: you select a single classification class, let us call it class 1. Then, you run the above algorithm to determine if each sample is in this class or not. It is binary choice. Then, you select the second classification class, say, class 2, and run the classification on the samples that are not in the class 1 to determine if they are in class 2 or not. And so on.

Comment: One-vs-one does another trick. You split all your classification classes in two groups: group 1 and group 2 of about the same number of samples. Say, group 1 is class1, class2, class3, and group2 is class4, class5, class 6. Then, you run a classification algorithm to determine if each sample is in group 1 or group 2. For each group, continue the process of splitting group to smaller ones until you get the class of interest.

Comment: @ kate-melnykova thank you, can you suggest an example of code ?? because I tried by searching but no valuable info, if you give me just a simple example by my code, I appreciate your help, I meaning so much for me.